# converting string of 'year, day of the year, hour,min,sec' value into 'year month day hour min sec'

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert a string of 'year, day of the year, hour, min, sec' value into 'year month day hour min sec'
i.e

```
0   2015 142 0 0 0.986
1   2015 142 0 0 1.017
2   2015 142 0 0 1.048
3   2015 142 0 0 1.079
4   2015 142 0 0 1.111
5   2015 142 0 0 1.142
6   2015 142 0 0 1.173
7   2015 142 0 0 1.204
8   2015 142 0 0 1.236
9   2015 142 0 0 1.267
```

into (2015 5 22 0:0:0.986).

I have found the below code..and tried this ...

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2015 142 0 0 0.986', '%Y %j %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

gives the following error

```
ValueError: time data '2015 142 0 0 0.986' does not match format '%Y %j %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

I have also tried:
separating the year, days, hour, min, sec column

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(142 - 1)+datetime.timedelta(hours=0,minutes=0,seconds=0.986)
```

It throws the error :

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: numpy.int64
```

any suggestion.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pattern is slightly off, and is using colons in the time portion, where no colons actually appear in the input string.  Try this version:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime('2015 142 0 0 0.986', '%Y %j %H %M %S.%f')
print(date)
```

This prints:

```
2015-05-22 00:00:00.986000
```